# Why window.getSelection () is different between firefox and chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

with:

```
<div contenteditable="true"> ... text.... <img src="image.png" height="50" width="50" onmouseup="alert(window.getSelection().isCollapsed)"> ... text... </div>
```

if I click (mouseup on img) in firefox alert says: 'false',
in chrome alert says: 'true'.
Why are different? (Firefox seems to indicate that there is selected text)

with:

```
<div contenteditable="true"> ... text.... <img src="image.png" alt="hello" height="50" width="50" onmouseup="alert(window.getSelection().toString())"> ... text... </div>
```

if I click (mouseup on img) in firefox alert says: 'hello',
in chrome alert says: ''.
Why does Firefox say I've selected the 'hello' text? Firefox wrong and chrome no?

Answer (score 1):

It is a known bug in firefox:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1417535

Answer (score 0):

The `document/window.getSelection` method works differently in Google Chrome, Safari and Internet Explorer than in Firefox and Opera. It returns a string in Firefox and Opera, and returns a selectionRange object in Google Chrome, Safari and Internet Explorer (the document.getSelection method is identical to the window.getSelection method in Google Chrome, Safari and Internet Explorer). Because of that, this method should not be used.

Comment: In my pc, the document/window.getSelection method returns an object (anchorNode, anchorOffset etc) also in firefox: 'alert(window.getSelection().isCollapsed)' says 'false'; if it was a string, 'window.getSelection()' with '.isCollapsed' would say 'undefined'...

Comment: @trewius so you would have to do a conditional about depending on the browser you are working on. But anyways I don't recommend using this method.

Comment: @TheUnnamed Could you recommend other solutions replace for  window.getSelection? Thanks.